# Como saber se um recurso está na cache do navegador?

Tags: javascript, cache, cross-browser

É possível descobrir, via JavaScript e sem nenhuma requisição HTTP adicional, se um determinado recurso está ou não na cache do navegador? E se está, obtê-lo também sem essa requisição?

No meu entendimento, quando o servidor envia um recurso de "longa duração" (i.e. um [*header* `Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) com um valor muito alto) o *browser* verifica - numa segunda consulta - se esse recurso existe em sua própria cache e sua validade ainda não expirou, caso em que nenhuma requisição adicional é feita. Entretanto, se tal recurso não é encontrado ou se está "vencido", a requisição é feita imediatamente - sem dar a chance ao programador de cancelá-la.

Gostaria de ter um pouco mais de controle sobre esse processo: se o recurso está na cache, use-o, caso contrário adote uma estratégia alternativa. Para isso seria necessário uma espécie de API JavaScript para consultar o estado da cache, creio eu, e até onde eu saiba isso não é possível - já que o *browser* abstrai sua cache do programador.

Existe algo - de preferência *cross-browsers* - que atenda a esse requisito? Ou talvez uma forma alternativa de se chegar ao mesmo resultado?

Obs.: Não estou interessado em soluções que envolvam o [*local storage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) - pois isso exigiria pegar os recursos que *já estão* na cache e salvar (e gerenciar) uma cópia dos mesmos nesse espaço já limitado.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de você renegar soluções com local storage, acho que essa seria a única alternativa para verificar o cache sem gerar uma requisição no servidor. Então segue abaixo uma ideia de como fazer, e não é preciso salvar todo o conteúdo do elemento, basta a string do src, e em 2mb consegue colocar pelo menos uns 50 mil.

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
if (!storage.ElementosNoCache) {
    storage.ElementosNoCache = "";
}

function RegistrarCache(src) {
    if (!VerificarCache(src)) {
        storage.ElementosNoCache += '[' + src + ']';
    }
}

function RemoverCache(src) {
    if (VerificarCache(src)) {
        storage.ElementosNoCache = storage.ElementosNoCache.replace('[' + src + ']', '');
    }
}

function VerificarCache(src) {
    return (storage.ElementosNoCache.indexOf('[' + src + ']', 0) >= 0);
}

function LimparCache() {
    storage.ElementosNoCache = "";
}
```

A automatização do registro pode ser feita com jquery, veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/7pv7898y/).

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, de fato não é preciso se guardar todo o recurso no local storage para se ter algum benefício (se eu salvar sua URL e sua data de expiração eu consigo dizer se ele *pode* estar na cache). Infelizmente, é uma roleta-russa: se a cache for limpa antes da hora, o registro no local storage não será notificado, de modo que eu vou acabar fazendo sim a requisição que eu estava tentando evitar. De todo modo, +1, pois pelo menos essa estratégia **reduz** o *overhead* em relação a "solução nenhuma" - ainda que não seja uma solução definitiva.